# CORS with Laravel 4 and external Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I am noob laravel and angular user. I have wrote very simple api a couple of day ago for learning how does work api. Now i am trying to reach it from another location with very simple angular script. This is my internal domain addres that i'm using instead of localhost/../.. : **http://3burcak.dev/api/v1/kategori** and this is the index method of kategori controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $cat = EmlakKategori::all();
    return Response::json(array(

        'cat'   => $cat->toArray(),
        ));
}
```

So, it is very simple.

When i try to reach it via my very simple angular js, i get OPTIONS 404 not found error if i don't use headers for cors. But if i use those headers inside of filters.php i get OPTIONS 500 Internal Server error.

```
App::before(function($request)
    {
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
            $statusCode = 204;

            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
            ];

            return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);});


    App::after(function($request, $response)
    {
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        return $response;
    });
```

Both situation, i see my json data in Response tab of Firebug... Here is the caps;

[Screenshot](http://i.hizliresim.com/KDGJZx.png)

And here is my very simple angular

```
function getKat($http, $scope)
    {
    $http({
        method: 'json',
        url: 'http://3burcak.dev/api/v1/kategori'
    })
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data.cat;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('error');
    });
    }
```

I couldn't solve this problem. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: If your Laravel app is producing a 500 error, then there's likely an error for you to check in the logs (`app/storage/logs`). What's showing up in there?

Comment: [2014-01-02 12:59:00] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected ')'' in C:\UniServer\www\3burcak\app\filters.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []

Comment: @fideloper thanks for answer, i fixed paranthesis problem, but now it says 204 no content, but i see data in response tab ? and chrome says Method JSON is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Comment: I solved problem, i changed method  from json to GET, i will answer and flag this tomorrow. thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved, 
I changed angular's method from json to GET and finally it works.

Comment: This is not really a useful answer to the problem at hand.